# unsupported format string passed to numpy.ndarray.__format__

Tags: python, machine-learning

I have array numpy

```
 a = array([[1.31927e-34],
           [5.46819e-38],
           [5.08072e-38],
           [5.07986e-35],
           [1.30973e-34],
           [1.99656e-34]], dtype=float32)
```

when I try to convert to float

```
for ele in a:
     float("{:.5f}".format(ele))
```

my error **unsupported format string passed to numpy.ndarray.**format****. Pls help me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the problem is your list is nested, i.e. 2D list. If we flatten it first (converting to 1D), then we can apply `float()` function on each element.

```
import numpy as np

a = np.array([[1.31927e-34],
              [5.46819e-38],
              [5.08072e-38],
              [5.07986e-35],
              [1.30973e-34],
              [1.99656e-34]], dtype='float32')

a_flatten = a.reshape(-1)

print(a_flatten)
[1.31927e-34 5.46819e-38 5.08072e-38 5.07986e-35 1.30973e-34 1.99656e-34]

for ele in a:
    print("{:.5f}".format(float(ele)))

0.00000
0.00000
0.00000
0.00000
0.00000
0.00000
```

They all end up being `0.00000` since they are way too small for us to represent in 5 decimals.

Comment: thanks your opinion, i understood my problem